# How to provide weekly profile by using R?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-analysis, bigdata

I got travel transaction data set like this (about 560000 trips): dataframe 1

```
ID        START TIME          DATE          ORIGIN  DESTINATION        DAY
1005          9.10            2012-01-02          A        B          Monday
1005          18.15           2012-01-02          B        A          Monday
1005          9.05            2012-01-08          A        B          Sunday
1005          17.05           2012-01-08          B        A          Sunday
1010          8.00            2012-01-09          A        C          Monday
1010          12.00           2012-01-09          C        A          Monday
1013          13.15           2012-01-10          D        E          Tuesday
1013          15.30           2012-01-10          E        G          Tuesday
1013          9.06            2012-01-12          D        E          Thursday
...            ...            2012-..-..          .        .           ...
```

and ID index like this (about 1986 IDs): Dataframe 2

```
 ID   
1005
1010
1013
1015
1030
1034
1036
1031
1040
...
```

I want to create a weekly travel profile based on these two dataframe. I'm not sure whether I'm right but I tried these codes:

```
    weekday = c("Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
    br = seq(0,23,by=1)
ranges = paste(head(br,-1), br[-1], sep="_")

            for (i in dataframe2$ID) {

                  for (n in weekday){
                    x= filter(dataframe1,dataframe1$ID %in% i & dataframe1$DAY %in% n)
                    freq = hist(as.numeric(x), br, include.lowest=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
                    df = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(frequency = freq$counts)))
                    df$i = i
                    df$n = n
                    colnames(df) = c(as.character(ranges),"ID","Day")
                    write.table(head(df),file="testdata1.csv", append=TRUE,sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
                  }
                }
```

I want to end up with a csv table containing their weekly trip frequency. I also want to ask if there is an easy way to simplify this task.

```
ID      0_1 1_2 2_3 3_4 4_5 5_6 6_7 7_8 8_9 9_10 10_11 11_12 12_13 13_14 14_15 15_16 16_17 17_18 18_19 19_20 20_21 21_22 22_23  Day
 1005    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0   Sunday  
 1005    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0   Monday
 1005    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   Tuesday
 1005                                                                                                                         Wednesday
 1005                                                                                                                         Thursday
 1005                                                                                                                           Friday
 1005                                                                                                                        Saturday
 1010                                                                                                                           Sunday
 1010
 1010
 1010
 1010
 1010
 1010
```

in the end I want to produce a diagram like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJ5K.jpg)

Comment: it's better if you `dput` your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in base R using the function `xtabs` but it may be a bit more clear if we do it using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.  With this approach, `weekday` is created as an R factor variable.  The `dplyr` function `mutate` is then used to convert `DAY` to a factor and `START_TIME` to an integer.  We next use `complete` from the `tidyr` package to create a new expanded data frame with a row for each value of `ID`, `DAY`, and `START_TIME` using their complete range of values (e.g. a row for each `ID`, for each start time in 0:23, and each day of the week.  The values for `DATE`, `ORIGIN`, and `DESTINATION` are used where they exist; otherwise the `DATE, ORIGIN,`and`DESTINATION` columns have `NA` values.  The number of trips per `ID, DAY,`and`START_TIME,` is computed as the sum of the rows which don't have `NA` for the value of `DATE`and stored in `Freq`.  The `spread` function from `tidyr` is used to convert each distinct value of `Freq` into a separate column.  Finally proper column names are assigned, the columns are arranged into the requested order, and the data frame written to a file as a csv.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
#
# input data is in df
# convert colunm name START TIME to syntactically correct version START_TIME
#
  colnames(df)[2] <- "START_TIME"
#
# define weekday as a factor with the days of week
#
     weekday <-  c("Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
     weekday <-  factor(weekday, levels=weekday)
#
#  sum number for trips by ID, DAY, and START_TIME
#
     trip_freq <- df %>% mutate(DAY = factor(DAY, levels=levels(weekday)),
                                START_TIME=floor(START_TIME)) %>%
                        complete(ID, DAY=weekday, START_TIME=0:23) %>% 
                        group_by(ID, DAY, START_TIME) %>%
                        summarise(Freq = sum(!is.na(DATE)))
    trip_freq_tbl <- trip_freq %>% spread(key = START_TIME, value=Freq)
#
# name and re-arrange columns
#
  colnames(trip_freq_tbl) <- c("ID", "Day", paste(0:23,1:24,sep="_"))
  trip_freq_tbl <- cbind(trip_freq_tbl[,-2], Day=trip_freq_tbl[,"Day"])            
#
# write trip_freq as csv fle
#
  write.table(trip_freq_tbl, file="testdata1.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```

You can further summarize the data for your plot with

```
#
# summarize the data for the plot
#
  trip_freq_plot <-  trip_freq %>% group_by(DAY, START_TIME) %>%
                                   summarize(Cnt = sum(Freq))
```